# How to write Linq query to check whether List have that id

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List inside that List one more List is there. How to check the `id` is present in any one of the List.

```
public class Users
{
    public virtual Userid { get; set; }
  
    public virtual List<UserCity> UserCities { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class UserCity
{
    public virtual UserCityId { get; set; }
  
    public virtual UserCityName { get; set; }
}
```

How to get the `users` which are having `Userid =usercityid`.

Linq query i tried  like this

```
List<Users> lstusers = new List<Users>();
lstusers = lstusers
    .Where(x=>x.UserCity.Any(w => w.UserCityId == w.Userid ))
    .ToList();
```

If the users have `usercityid` with same `userid` i need to get those `users`.

Comment: Are you sure that `UserCityId` has userid stored in it? Why not run query `lstusers.Where(x=>x.UserId).To list();`

Comment: In your classes, how can you use `public virtual` without any datatype? E.g. `public virtual Userid`?

Comment: I assume that `UserCity` is a bridge table between `User` and `City`. In this case it most probably has a `UserId` (FK), a `CityId` (FK) and a `UserCityId` (PK). But the user itself must have a `UserId` as @Chetan pointed out. So, it makes no sense to test the user cities. Also, `UserCityId` != `UserId`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your query. Try this:

```
// create a dummy list for testing
var lstusers = new List<Users>
{
   new Users {Userid = 1, UserCities = new List<UserCity>{ new UserCity { UserCityId = 1, UserCityName="xxx"} }  }
};
// execute the linq-query
lstusers = lstusers.Where(x => x.UserCities.Any(w => w.UserCityId == x.Userid)).ToList();
// and print the number of users found
Console.WriteLine($"Number of users found: {lstusers.Count}");
```

Comment: there is no compilations error. but I'm not getting records with that. getting 0 records.

Comment: @krishna mohan: In that case set a breakpoint on the line with the query. Once that breakpoint is hit, check if `lstusers` contains any users that meet the condition... Propably there are none so you get an empty list...